# Class Cast Exception for Connection Object

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to establish a connection for MySQL but I'm getting a class cast exception. Here is the code. The password, username, etc. have been changed but that isn't the issue. The main issue is the Class Cast Exception I get when I try to do

```
Connection c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);
```

CODE

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


 public class Connection {
    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname";
            String un = "username";
            String pw = "password";
            Connection c = (Connection)   DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the import for the connection that you are trying to cast to ?

Comment: I didn't have an import. This is the complete version of the code I was writing to test the database.

Comment: Rename your class to 'Connection1' or something else and import `java.sql.Connection`

Comment: The connection that you should use is "java.sql.Connection".  In your code, the sql.Connection is being casted to your class "Connection" which is causing the issue. Just rename you class file and use the above import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Connection
```

The problem is right here. Class ambiguity problem. Rename your class, and fix your imports to include `java.sql.Connection.`

Answer (score 2):

`DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);` returns a `java.sql.Connection`.
So you have to change to

```
java.sql.Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);
```

The return value i not a instance of your Connection class.

Comment: This can be used without renaming your class. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The connection that `DriverManager.getConnection()` returns is an instance of `java.sql.Connection` but see that you have defined a separate Connection class thinking it to be unique. Turns out, it is already a standard class defined by `java.sql.Connection`.

If you use an import for Connection then there will be a conflict between the classes with same name. Rename your class to say MyConnection and `import java.sql.Connection` then your code is gonna work.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

 public class MyConnection {
    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://hostname/dbname";
            String un = "username";
            String pw = "password";
            Connection c = (Connection)   DriverManager.getConnection(url,un,pw);
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.sql.Exception`? What is that? What does that have to do with it? What does that 'define'?

Comment: @EJP : Typo class can describe it maybe. ;)

Comment: Typo schmypo. There is no such thing, and it therefore cannot 'define' anything.

Comment: @EJP : I apologize, I answered hurriedly. Thx for telling me